# Why does excel AVERAGE change when changing the number format of cells?

Tags: excel, rounding

I've got an Excel sheet which is exhibiting strange behaviour. I have 2 values, followed by an average of those 2 values - simple enough, right?

[image]

However, if I change the number format of the top cell from 2 decimal places to 30, I get a different result:

[image]

Can anyone explain this? When a cell is formatted to 2 decimal places, does that mean all formulae using this cell are rounding the value to 2 decimal places also?

Comment: @pnuts - sorry, should have done that - its 1.730000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Excel options (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>) for the Advanced ► When calculating this workbook ► Set precision as displayed option. When this is checked, calculation is automatically rounded off to the displayed number of decimals rather than the internal 15 digit floating point precision. It also permanently truncates the raw value to the displayed precision so I am unclear on how you are bouncing between the two average values.

The actual average of 1.6786427146 and 1.73 is 1.7043213573 which is 1.70 when only two decimals are displayed. It would only be through *Precision as displayed* that 1.6786427146 would actually be converted to 1.68 making the average 1.71.

Turn the option off and the underlying raw value will be stored to a 15 digit floating point precision. The same goes for all internal formula calculations.

Comment: You are correct! I'd never heard of this setting before. To me, it seems like a bad idea not to use the actual number when doing calculations...

Comment: do you know if is this the default setting in Excel?

Comment: @user1578653 - No, this is not the default but once set, it is carried by the workbook; e.g. it doesn't reset the Excel application environment, just that workbook, even if the workbook gets copied somewhere else. I've never had much use for it but others who habitually run into floating point match errors (another Excel nightmare) find truncating the values to the displayed precision worthwhile. Two examples of this would be time and tax calculations since both often run into repeating decimals that can cause floating point errors.